# Add property to existing Control (ComboBox or ListView)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm designing simply 'forms generator'. 
I'm loading UI from previously generated xaml file (by XamlReader)
I have for example:

```
<StackPanel Background="Gray">
<ComboBox Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Header="testheader" DisplayMemberPath="EventDate"  />
</StackPanel>
```

What I want to achieve is saving some additional text information in xaml file, which will not be loaded to UI by XamlReader. 
So I thought about add some additional string property to Control like 'AddtionalInfo'.

```
<StackPanel Background="Gray">
<ComboBox Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Header="testheader" DisplayMemberPath="EventDate" AdditionalInfo="test"  />
</StackPanel>
```

I've tried do that by creating custom control, but then XamlReder don't want to read it. 
Maybe someone has better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a property designed specially for this:

> `public object Tag { get; set; }`
>       Member of Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement
>
> **Summary**: Gets or sets an arbitrary object value that can be used to
>   store custom information about this object.

Just use this property to store any data you want on any `FrameworkElement`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Attached Property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview

```
 public class SomeClass
 {
    public static DependencyProperty AdditionalInfoProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AdditionalInfo", typeof(string),typeof(SomeClass),new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public static void SetAdditionalInfo(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AdditionalInfoProperty, value);
    }
    public static string GetAdditionalInfo(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(AdditionalInfoProperty);
    }
}
```

Usage of the Property:

```
    <StackPanel Background="Gray">
      <ComboBox Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Header="testheader" DisplayMemberPath="EventDate" myNamespace:SomeClass.AdditionalInfo="test"  />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how Can I use this property? Can I use this property in xaml and load it by Xaml Reader?

Comment: I think you should be able to read it with XamlReader after you have declared it in XAML